# Serialize List<LinkedListNode<object>> using Json.net

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

example of code with string also throws exception:

```
LinkedList<string> l = new LinkedList<string>();
        l.AddLast("Kuku");
        l.AddLast("Riku");
        l.AddLast("Ok");
        List<LinkedListNode<string>> lst = new List<LinkedListNode<string>>();
        lst.Add(l.First);
        lst.Add(l.First.Next);
        lst.Add(l.Last);

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst, Formatting.Indented,
       new JsonSerializerSettings
       {
           ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
       });
        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Student Routine\Data.txt", json);`
```

I can not serialize `List<LinkedListNode<object>>` due to a self-referral error, using Json.net.

the error:Self referencing loop detected for property 'Previous' with type 'System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`1[Calendar_Module.ScheduleEvent]'. Path '[0].UserData.Calendar.Days.2017-04-02T00:00:00[0].Next.Next.Next.Next.Next.Next'.

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Serializing a `List<LinkedListNode<string>>` is a bit of an odd thing to do - normally one would just serialize the underlying linked list.  Perhaps you're trying to serialize a table that gives the nodes in a different order than the underlying list?

If that's the case, it might appear that one could serialize the node list using [`PreserveReferencesHandling.All`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveReferencesHandlingObject.htm) combined with [`ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReferenceLoopHandlingIgnore.htm), however this fails due to some limitations of Json.NET:

- `PreserveReferencesHandling` is not implemented for read-only properties (see [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1140)) but [`LinkedListNode.List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h339c45b(v=vs.110).aspx), [`.Next`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b4t9w6be(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`.Previous`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de80z2x6(v=vs.110).aspx) are all read-only.  This prevents correct serialization of circular dependencies and eventually leads to an infinite recursion on the next and previous node properties.
- `PreserveReferencesHandling` is not implemented for objects with non-default constructors (see [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/715)) but the only public constructor for [`LinkedListNode<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24y0zx74(v=vs.110).aspx) is parameterized.

Thus, you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for your list of nodes:

```
public class LinkedListNodeListConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(List<LinkedListNode<T>>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var list = (existingValue as IList<LinkedListNode<T>> ?? (IList<LinkedListNode<T>>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
        var table = serializer.Deserialize<LinkedListNodeOrderTable<T>>(reader);
        foreach (var node in table.ToNodeList())
            list.Add(node);
        return list;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var list = (IList<LinkedListNode<T>>)value;
        var table = LinkedListNodeOrderTable<T>.FromList(list);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, table);
    }
}

class LinkedListNodeOrderTable<T>
{
    public static LinkedListNodeOrderTable<T> FromList(IList<LinkedListNode<T>> nodeList)
    {
        if (nodeList == null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            var list = nodeList.Where(n => n != null).Select(n => n.List).Distinct().SingleOrDefault();
            var table = new LinkedListNodeOrderTable<T>(list);
            var dictionary = list == null ? null : list.EnumerateNodes().Select((n, i) => new KeyValuePair<LinkedListNode<T>, int>(n, i)).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
            table.Indices = nodeList.Select(n => (n == null ? -1 : dictionary[n])).ToList();
            return table;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Failed to construct LinkedListNodeOrderTable<{0}>",  typeof(T)), ex);
        }
    }

    public LinkedListNodeOrderTable(LinkedList<T> List)
    {
        this.List = List;
    }

    public LinkedList<T> List { get; set; }

    public List<int> Indices { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> ToNodeList()
    {
        if (Indices == null || Indices.Count < 1)
            return Enumerable.Empty<LinkedListNode<T>>();
        var array = List == null ? null : List.EnumerateNodes().ToArray();
        return Indices.Select(i => (i == -1 ? null : array[i]));
    }
}

public static class LinkedListExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> EnumerateNodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        if (list == null)
            yield break;
        for (var node = list.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
            yield return node;
    }
}
```

And use the following settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new LinkedListNodeListConverter<string>() },
};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lst, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

The resulting JSON will look like:

```
{
  "List": [
    "Kuku",
    "Riku",
    "Ok"
  ],
  "Indices": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

Note that the converter assumes all the nodes in the list are members of the same underlying `LinkedList<T>`.  If not an exception will be thrown.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/moURJn).

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type System.Collections.Generic.LinkedListNode`1[System.String] is not marked as Serializable.
```

In other words, don't use LinkedListNode if you intend to serialize it…

Comment: it is possible, but there is a problem with the references. and if you used BinarryFormatter you need the Serializable attribute